# JavaFX AnchorPane is not working

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to anchor two rectangles using an `AnchorPane`, although for some reason this doesn't seem to work:

**Normal Screen**

[image]

**Maximized Screen**

[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mip4z.png)
This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage MainStage) throws Exception {

        // Setup window
        MainStage.setTitle("Minx IDE - Version 1.0.0");
        Group Root = new Group();
        Scene MainScene = new Scene(Root, 1000, 600, Color.rgb(44, 62, 80));
        MainStage.setScene(MainScene);
        MainStage.show();

        // Setup window components
        // Info box
        Rectangle InfoBox = RectangleBuilder.create()
                .x(700)
                .y(0)
                .width(300)
                .height(600)
                .fill(Color.rgb(149, 165, 166))
                .build();

        // Save bar
        Rectangle SaveBar = RectangleBuilder.create()
                .x(0)
                .y(575)
                .width(700)
                .height(25)
                .fill(Color.rgb(52, 152, 219))
                .build();

        AnchorPane Anchor = new AnchorPane(InfoBox, SaveBar);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(SaveBar, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(SaveBar, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(InfoBox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(InfoBox, 0.0);

        // Add components to root and anchor
        Root.getChildren().addAll(InfoBox, SaveBar);

    }
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: try `Root.getChildren().add(Anchor);`

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work? What is your desired output and how is it different from the actual output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you need the rectangles to be anchored at their respective location irrespective of the screen size, you need to remove the Group as the root of the Scene and make the AnchorPane the root of the scene.

[Group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) layout does not resize automatically and retains the size of its children.

Creating a scene with the `anchorPane` as the root will resolve your issue, since it will resize itself depending of the availability of space.

```
Scene mainScene = new Scene(anchorPane, 1000, 600, Color.WHITE);
```

**Note :**

1. `RectangleBuilder` is deprecated in JavaFX 8, so avoid using it.
2. Try to use [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) when you are naming your variables. It is the default naming convention followed in Java.

Comment: Thank you! how would I go about stretching the rectangle?

Comment: It depends on what do you want to stretch. More information would be helpful in answering your question.

Comment: Stretch the `InfoBox` to the bottom and stretch the `SaveBar` across the width of the window